# How to access Odoo 12 using WSL

Tags: port, odoo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, odoo-12

I have installed Odoo 12 in Ubuntu 18.04LTS as WSL, everything seems fine and the service is running. However, I am lost on how to access Odoo page. I have tried `0.0.0.0:8069` in Windows (Chrome) but it says that:

> This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8069/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

I have another installation for odoo running in the same port `localhost:8069`. I tried to stop the service by visiting `0.0.0.0:8069` but that also didn't work.

Any help on that?

Also, please let me know how I can change the Port for Odoo in Ubuntu in WSL.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found what the error was.

The problem was a conflict with the port number for Odoo Windows and Odoo Ubuntu WSL. I only changed the Port number for one of them (I choose the Local Windows version) and now I have both versions are running:

Odoo windows running via localhost:9999
Odoo Ubuntu WSL running via localhost:8069

Thanks

Comment: When you see an "Internal Server Error" you need to check the Odoo log to find the actual error.

Comment: The error is related to Database and ports, I have raised a new question with that as it's a different issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803034/odoo-12-in-wsl-psycopg2-doesnt-get-the-right-port-for-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

0. Check that your odoo server is actually running CORRECTLY (service odoo status, etc.)
1. Ping your VM from the host. Don't try anything else unless you get a ping back.
2. Try accesing http://localhost:8069 ( NOT http**s**:// )
3. Check that your odoo.conf is actually configured to point to port 8069
4. Disable nginx a/o apache reverse proxies in the VM client.